# Android Generate Key with Password

Tags: android, security, key

**Objective**: Save encrypted Data to SharedPreferences

**Article I am following**: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/storing-data-securely-on-android--cms-30558

**Problem**: In the article, it shows that the key gets generated by a given password that's provided by the user. But, I don't really want this.

All I want to do is simply encrypt and decrypt. Not involve the user in any way.

My solution is to have a String that's in the Encryption class which is a randomly generated string that will act as the password so that the code will run with a given static password.

I am also not going to store the string plain, but as maybe an array of bites so that at least if someone decompiles the APK, the password doesn't show as a string when performing the /strings command in terminal.

Is this a sound approach?

Code:

```
//regenerate key from password
char[] passwordChar = passwordString.toCharArray(); <--- Here, the password provided by the user
PBEKeySpec pbKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passwordChar, salt, 1324, 256);
SecretKeyFactory secretKeyFactory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
byte[] keyBytes = secretKeyFactory.generateSecret(pbKeySpec).getEncoded();
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "AES");
```

Comment: If you store this passphrase in your application, then your app will be less secure - but in truth, do you really need to encrypt what you put inside `SharedPreferences`? It's in a section of storage that's visible only to that application.

Comment: @PPartisan Yes, there is a need to store encrypted data.

Comment: I guess I could make the function which calls the encryption provide the password.